# search for multiple words in file

Tags: linux, search, grep

If I wish to search for occurrence of a word in a file using grep I use

```
grep token file
```

what if I wish to search for lines where it contains multiple tokens, pseudo code:

```
grep "token1 and token2" file
```

how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing coming to mind is

```
grep token1 file | grep -h token2
```

If you wanted to match patterns in a particular order, consider regex:

```
grep -E 'token1(.*?)token2' file
```

To matches of `token1` and `token2` (in any line), I'd do

```
grep -e token1 -e token2 *.cpp
```

To list only the filenames of matched files, not the particular matching lines:

```
grep -l -e token1 -e token2 *.cpp
```

Comment: the second grep is searching in the output of the first grep not in the initial file

Comment: I fail to see the difference

Comment: if you have one line with token1 and second line with token2
this grep will show nothing

you need to use something like this:

grep -e token1 -e token2

Comment: @Ovi-WanKenobi that's exactly what the question is about

Comment: urgh? 
I got it wrong then.
if you edit your answer I'll vote it

Comment: @Ovi-WanKenobi I elaborated my answer to make thing a bit more explicit

Answer (score 1):

Grep doesn't have an AND operator, you can use awk instead:

```
awk '/token1/ && /token2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep token1 file | grep token2
```